# How to properly create .config files to launch electron apps in native wayland? [Ubuntu 22.10]

Tags: wayland, visual-studio-code, electron

While using fractional scaling, electron apps are blurry. To fix that I used the following flags

```
$code --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland --enable-features=WaylandWindowDecorations
```

There was [an article on arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wayland) that suggested to make electron-config files. I followed it but vs code still launches blurry. I think, I made some mistake while adding flags to the config files. Please tell me how do I fix the issue.

[Info about VS Code, screenshots of config files and their location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DT7w.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those *-flags.conf files are an Arch modification, I don't think Ubuntu does it.

You can copy your application's .desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications and edit the Exec= line to add the flags. Anything there will override the one in /usr/share/applications.